# Generate multilevel list in jade / keystone

Tags: node.js, pug, keystonejs

I have an array:

```
res.locals.navLinks = [
    { label: 'Main', key: 'home', href: '/' },
    { label: 'About', key: 'about', href: '/about'},
    { label: 'Contacts', key: 'contact', href: '/contact' },
    { label: 'Projects', key: 'gallery', href: '/gallery' },
    { label: 'Blog', key: 'blog', href: '/blog' },
    { label: 'Commission', key:'commission', href:'/Commission'},
    { label: 'Gov Control', key: 'govControl', href: '/govControl'}
];
```

need to render multilevel list in jade for main menu, like this

```
ul **(first five objects)***
 li(class=(section == link.key ? 'active' : null)): a(href=link.href)= link.label
 li Partners
   ul **(last two objects)**
     li(class=(section == link.key ? 'active' : null)): a(href=link.href)= link.label
```

now i can render only one level list with code:

```
each link in navLinks
  li(class=(section == link.key ? 'active' : null)): a(href=link.href)= link.label
```

It may be any working solution, with 2 arrays or another. I`m tied trying,   i`m new in programming it`s total frustration. Will thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The literal solution is something like this:

```
each link, index in navLinks
  if index < 5
    li(class=(section == link.key ? 'active' : null)): a(href=link.href)= link.label
  else if index < navLinks.length
    li
      ul
        while index < navLinks.length
          li(class=(section == navLinks[index].key ? 'active' : null)): a(href=navLinks[index].href)= navLinks[index].label
          index++
```

You might consider restructuring `navLinks` so the items for the nested list are in another array.

Comment: Jade not understand last line as increment and say: "Warning: missing space before text". Without increment infinite loop crashed app. May be solution with 2 arrays will be simpler, but i`m was try and can not get correct list.